# include does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having a problem with include/require commands.

the file structure looks like this:

```
private |
        - config.php
        - dbc.php
public |
       - index.php
       - includes |
                  - database.php
```

here is the image for better understanding 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHm5C.png

in config file i have this:

```
  <?php 
  $dbname = "Prehlad_oop";
  $dbuser = "lifestype_oop";
  $dbpass = "fwoop";
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  ?>
```

in dbc.php i have this:

```
 public function c(){
 include "config.php";
 $this->conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
 .... other code
```

and in database.php:

```
 require '../private/dbc.php';
 $conn = new connection;
 $conn->c();
```

this thing is working when i load it from dbc.php, however, if i load the page from the database.php, it doesn't work, says i have undefined  variables in dbc.php

i found a way to make this code work, even when i call if from the database.php, by adding

```
 ../private/
```

in dbc.php... final code looks like this:

```
public function c(){
include "../private/config.php";
```

my question is, why would i need to go up in directory path, when the file i want to include is in the same directory ( config.php and dbc.php). This error occurs only when i call the function from database.php. Are there some obstacles when i include a file inside included file, etc??
ty for the answers :-)

Comment: include/require with relative paths search relative to the entries listed in the php.ini `include_path` directive, which typically includes the current working directory. So they are relative to the __current working directory__, not necessarily to the directory where the file doing the include is located.... understand this, and you'll understand includes... it's something that many PHP developers never fully understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use the absolute path of the file to include.
e.g

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."config.php";
```

Instead of relative path of `config.php` file.

Include all files with their absolute path.
As suggested by Rigg's

You can use `__DIR__` (Which is a better option)

So you can move script anywhere in web-project tree without changes.

Comment: You would be better using `__DIR__` so that if/when the site is moved to a sub folder of the `documentroot` folder in a testing environment it continues to work, where `DOCUMENT_ROOT` would not

Comment: so what would i then type?

Comment: require __DIR__ . "config.php"; ??? or do i have to somehow define the __DIR__ ??

Answer (score 0):

Either include './private/config.php'; or include 'private/config.php', the first version looks for the file, relative to the current working directory, the second uses the include path.

PS: best use require_once or include_once, to avoid including the same function/class definitions multiple times, which will casuse issues (redeclaring functions)

Answer (score 0):

Mangesh's answer is good (I upvoted it), but I propose this in my opinion, slightly better alternative:

```
<?php
require_once(realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) . '/project_folder/file.php');
?>
```

I've found this to work better, in other words, more consistently across web servers, since [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) returns canonicalized absolute pathname, and that's what we always tend to have, don't we?

*Notice:* realpath will strip away any trailing slashes of its path argument, so be sure to have a leading slash after the function (before the *projeft_folder*, in this case).

In any case, you can use that require/include format across all your project files, and it will work. **Stay away from relative paths, they're trouble.**